# How to change color of the terminal using Python

Tags: python

I am making my own terminal and I want to change all text colors to the user input. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to provide way more context for this question. What do you mean by making your own terminal? Are you building a terminal application or are you customizing a terminal?

If you mean you are running a python application and want to color the output of the script then consider using `colorama`

https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Comment: I want to make my own terminal like this: https://github.com/Cyber-Coding-Scripts/Terminal/blob/main/code.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) like this: `\033[CODE_HERE;ANOTHER_CODE_HEREmYOUR_CONTENT_HERE`.

Example for bold + blinking text (`\033[0m` is to reset display to default values):

```py
print("\033[1;5mdede\033[0m")
```

Another example:

```py
print("\033[1;41mRed bold text\033[0;41mRed normal text\033[0mnormal text")
```

Will result to:

[[image: screenshot of previous example]]